# How to calculate the fraction of a certain letter within a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I would like to know how I can calculate the fraction of certain letters in a string. Like for example if I have the string "ABGTACTGASDJASBFGJAFKA" and want to calculate the fraction of A+D in that string what would I have to do? I want to do this without having to import anything and only using the built in functions of python.

```
def fraction(string):
    A = ""
    D = ""
    A = string.count("A")
    D = string.count("D")
    print(int(A/D * 100), "%")
```

Comment: This smells like homework. What have you tried to solve this problem? Furthermore, some input and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: I edited the question and put in what I have, I keep getting an error for it saying that A and D are undefined

Comment: Replace == with =

Comment: Your code does not appear to correspond to the question very much.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, sorry, I was testing it out with different letters, and forgot to edit it correctly

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, Thank You!!!!

Comment: `A/D` is not a meaningful percent

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The `==` values get ignored anyway

Comment: I changed the code again, and now when it outputs, there is a space between the number that is outputted and the % sign, how can I make it so that it prints example: 83% as an output instead of 83 %?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A/D` is not a the fraction of a certain letter in the whole sting.

The following line will calculate the percentage of "A" in your string.

```
100.0 * ( string.count("A") / len(string) )
```

My suggestion, don't do both characters at once. Start with this

```
def fraction(string, letter):
```

Comment: I am startin to get a better understanding of it now, thank you!!!!